# How to correctly return from stored procedure in Sql to model?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I need to return list of values from stored procedure to my model. How do I do it:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
    public DataSource Get(int id)
    {
        DataSource ds = _dbContext.DataSources.Where(d => d.Id == id)
            .Include(d => d.DataSourceParams)
                .ThenInclude(p => p.SelectOptions).FirstOrDefault();

        foreach(DataSourceParam p in ds.DataSourceParams)
        {
            if(p.TypeId == 5)
            {
                p.SelectOptions = _dbContext.SelectOptions.FromSql("Exec " + ds.DataBaseName + ".dbo." + "procGetTop50 " + ds.Id + ", 1").ToList();
            }    
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, declare your procedure with parameters:

```
string sql = "myProcedure @param1, @param2";
```

Second, create parameters

```
var param1 = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "param1", Value = param1Value};
var param2 = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "param2", Value = param2Value };
```

Finally, exec the code:

```
info = this.DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<MyModel>(sql, param1, param2).FirstOrDefault();
```

This is it!

**Just remember** your model must match with the procedure columns. With means, if your procedure returns a column named 'MyProp' your model 'MyModel' must have a 'MyProp' property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but SqlQuery doesn't exist in EF7. It has been replaced with FromSql, but I dont know how to use it